# can anyone help me how to use ngrx local storage to encrypt and decrpt data

Tags: javascript, angular, state, ngrx

how to use ngrx local storage to encrypt and decrypt my data in store

```
export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
     return localStorageSync({ keys: ['product']}, rehydate:true)(reducer);
}

export const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax to follow to add encryption and decryption directly on your export function...

```
export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({
    keys: [{'product': {
      encrypt: state => ****ENTER YOUR ENCRYPTION FUNCTION HERE****,
      decrypt: state => ****ENTER YOUR DECRYPTION FUNCTION HERE****
    }}],
    rehydrate: true
  })(reducer);
}
```

And here is what it would look like if we used the base64 encrypt/decrypt rule...

```
export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({
    keys: [{'product': {
      encrypt: state => btoa(state),
      decrypt: state => atob(state)
    }}]
  })(reducer);
}
```

The **btoa(state)** and **atob(state)** are in built JavaScript functions. (Correct me if i'm wrong).

If you would like to design your own encrypt/decrypt rules, then replace **btoa(state)** and/or **atob(state)** to your own functions.

I would recommend this because anyone could copy the base64 encryption, then decrypt it easily with any online tool.

Side-Note:
Someone had created a pull request to put the documentation for the encrpyt/decrypt for ngrx-store-localstorage but it has not been accepted by the author for over 3 months.

Here is the link if you would like to read the pull request...
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage/pull/137

If took me far too long to figure out the syntax but I got it in the end.

Enjoy your day. :)